# Add foreign key produces an error "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint"

Tags: mysql

```
  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `users` (
  `id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `first_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `is_email_verify` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `phone_no` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `password` varchar(255) NOT NULL,
  `status` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `role` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'employee',
  `photo` varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) DEFAULT '0',
  `shift_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `shift_date` date NOT NULL,
  `created` datetime NOT NULL,
  `updated` datetime NOT NULL,
  `first_off` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `second_off` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_maps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_project_id` (`project_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
COMMIT;
```

I am trying to map project_map.user_id to user table.. by using

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_project_users FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES project_maps(user_id);
```

Produces an error "#1215 - Cannot add foreign key constraint" can any one explain why ?

Comment: Your alter table statement does not do what you think it does. It's written to do the opposite of your stated objective. Don't alter the users table. Alter the project_maps table.

Comment: For which table you want to assign Foreign Key ?

Comment: I want to create associations belongsTo - from project_map.user_id -> users.first_name. Can you explain how to do that.

Comment: @SamM Good catch, it helps to read the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a foreign key constraint to `project_maps`, not `users`:

```
ALTER TABLE project_maps
ADD CONSTRAINT fk_project_users
FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES users (id);
```

But besides this, the user ID column types are not the same in your two tables.  In the `users` table you declare it to be an unsigned int:

```
`id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

while in the `project_maps` table you use a different definition:

```
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
```

Just use the same definition in both tables and you should be able to add the constraint:

```
int(11) NOT NULL
```

FYI integers default to being signed in MySQL, unless you explicitly make them unsigned.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying the define a foreign key from **project_maps(user_id)**,

So here is the issue,

You cannot assign foreign key reference to non key column (user_id),

If you want to create foreign key column, then create a Key for user_id as you did for project_id in project_maps table

as follow

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `project_maps` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `project_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `user_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  `group_id` int(11) UNSIGNED DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `fk_project_id` (`project_id`),
  KEY `fk_user_id` (`user_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

Then your alter query will work as expected

```
ALTER TABLE users ADD CONSTRAINT fk_project_users FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES project_maps(user_id);
```